# How to draw Line Chart Graphs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have line chart in that I am unable to draw the last point of that graph. For example when I have three values in data table the graph only shows two values.

This is what I tried:

```
string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
}

LineChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Data = y });
LineChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);
LineChart1.Visible = true;

if (x.Length > 0)
{
    LineChart1.ChartWidth = (x.Length * 100).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer the below link. may help you

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Line-Chart-Control-Multiple-Series-Populate-from-Database-example.aspx

Thanks

Comment: thank you for your response but i am same way to draw that graph but i am not getting last point. and also please tell me how can i set chart position in center could  you please tell me